# How to disable system autocorrect?

Tags: settings, keyboard, dictionary, auto-correct

Gboard has a toggle to disable/enable spellcheck completely, but using 3rd-party keyboards such as AnySoftKeyboard or SwiftKey shows this red-underline and suggestion-box that cannot be disabled.

[image: spellcheck]

The spellcheck is actually part of the Android system, not part of AnySoftKeyboard.

How can I disable spellcheck for the whole system? Or does the developer of the keyboard app always need to implement this feature?

In case it's relevant, I'm on Android 10, ColorOS 7.

Comment: Hi, it seems you accidentally created a duplicate account. Please refer to [the help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts and regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 8.0+:

Go to `System -> Languages and Input -> Spell Checker -> Toggle use spell checker off`

Depending on your device the location of that toggle may be different

Comment: unfortunately that setting is not there, and searching settings via searchbox turns up nothing, and i found nothing by manually searching settings.

Comment: @Keyboardbug I have little experience with ColorOS

Comment: @Keyboardbug have you tried https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JJpcKQt5qEU